# Vercel failing to import images (Module not found or Rollup failed to resolve import)

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite, vercel

Everytime I try to deploy my app on vercel, it fails by saying module not found error or rollup failed to resolve import, any time there is a local image being imported. App works perfectly on localhost and I can also run npm run build, no errors. Only when deploying this issue happens. Please send help, losing my mind.
[image]

I expect the app to be deployed since I can compile the build. App was created using Vite.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because of case insensitivity of files on macOS, while on linux it's the opposite. I can see that you have a capitalized D for your file `Data.js`. Try to remove it.